# Regex specific number inside quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regex and have this cdn url that returns `text` and I want to use javascript to match and extract the version number. I can match the latestVersion but I am not sure how to get the value inside of it.

ex on `text`:

```
...oldVersion:"1.2.0",stagingVersion:"1.2.1",latestVersion:"1.3.0",authVersion:"2.2.2"...
```

I tried doing this line to display `latestVersion:"1.3.0` but not successful

```
const regex = /\blatestVersion:"*"\b/
stringIneed = text.match(regex)
```

And I only need `1.3.0` not including the string  `latestVersion:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lookbehind, or a capturing group like this:

```js
const str = '...oldVersion:"1.2.0",stagingVersion:"1.2.1",latestVersion:"1.3.0",authVersion:"2.2.2"...'

console.log(
  str.match(/(?<=latestVersion:")[^"]+/)?.[0]
)

console.log(
  str.match(/latestVersion:"([^"]+)"/)?.[1]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of doing it. This is one:

```js
const text='...oldVersion:"1.2.0",stagingVersion:"1.2.1",latestVersion:"1.3.0",authVersion:"2.2.2"...';

console.log(text.match(/latestVersion:"(.*?)"/)?.[1])
```

The `.*?` is a "non-greedy" wildcard that will match as few as possible characters in order to make the whole regexp match. For this reason it will stop matching before the `"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a capture group `()` to match certain strings in the Regex.

```
/\blatestVersion:"([0-9.]+)"/
```

Comment: This is giving me 2 results on array
0: "latestVersion:\"1.3.0\""
1: "1.3.0"

Comment: It looks like it works to me, you just need to use the second element of the array.

Comment: Yeah it works too by selecting the second element